# dompdf no carga todos los datos del html que le envio

Tags: php, javascript

este es el pdf que me genera faltan los datos de la primera columna[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo php donde tengo una funcion

```
public function ventas($link,$mes_inicio,$mes_finalizacion,$año)
{
    $fecha="01/".$mes_inicio."/".$año;
    $fecha2="30/".$mes_finalizacion."/".$año;
    $sql=oci_parse($link, "SELECT *FROM VENTA WHERE FECHA_COMPRA BETWEEN '$fecha' AND '$fecha2'");
    if(oci_execute($sql))
    {
        $sql1=oci_parse($link, "SELECT FOTO FROM EMPRESA"); 
        if(oci_execute($sql1))
         {
            if($row1=oci_fetch_array($sql1))
            {
                if(is_null($row1["FOTO"]))
                {
                    echo "error al cargar fotografia";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<div class='encabezado'><a hre='#' class='imagen'><img src='../".$row1['FOTO']."'></img></a><h5>INFORME DE LAS VENTAS EN GENERAL</h5></div><div class='encabezado'><h5>DE:$fecha</h5><h5>AL:$fecha2</h5></div>";
                    echo "<div class='titulo'><h5>USUARIO</h5></div><div class='titulo'><h5>FECHA</h5></div><div class='titulo'><h5>CANTIDAD PRODUCTOS</h5></div><div class='titulo'><h5>TOTAL VENDIDO</h5></div>";
                    while($row=oci_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                        echo "<div><h5>".$row["ID_USUARIO"]."</h5></div><div><h5>".$row["FECHA_COMPRA"]."</h5></div><div><h5>".$row["CANTIDAD_TOTAL"]."</h5></div><div><h5>Q.".$row["PRECIO_TOTAL"]."</h5></div>";
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error en la asociacion";
            }
         }
         else
         {
            echo "Error en consulta";
         }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "error en consulta";
    }
}
```

aqui le envio el html al dompdf

```
<?php require_once '../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
require_once '../dompdf/lib/html5lib/Parser.php';
require_once '../dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/Autoloader.php';
require_once '../dompdf/lib/php-svg-lib/src/autoload.php';
require_once '../dompdf/src/Autoloader.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true);
session_name('ADMINISTRADOR');
session_start();
ini_set("memory_limit", "128M");
$html = $_SESSION['pdf']['content'];//obtenemos la factura  de la sesion a la   variable $html
$filename = $_SESSION['pdf']['filename'];//obtenemos el nombre de la factura que  esta en la sesion a la variable $filename
unset($_SESSION['pdf']);// Borramos la variable de sesión
$dompdf = new Dompdf();//creamos una nueva clase de dompdf
$dompdf->setPaper('A4','portrait'); // (Opcional) Configurar papel y 
orientación'portrait''landscape'
$dompdf->loadHtml(utf8_encode($html));//agregamos el contenido de la factura por 
medio de la variable $html
$dompdf->render(); // Generar el PDF desde contenido HTML
$pdf = $dompdf->output(); // Obtener el PDF generado
$dompdf->stream($filename); // Enviar el PDF generado al navegador y por medio 
de la variable $filename indicamos el nombre
?>
```

Comment: Buenos días @Jose, deberías colocar algo de código de tus intentos. Almenos algo en lo que puedan basarse las personas que van a ayudarte. Echale un vistazo a [ask]. Suerte!

Comment: gracias ya  agregue el codigo, ya llevo ya rato revisando y no encuentro donde esta el error